# Authentication with Fullstack App with Next.js, Prisma, and Vercel Postgres not working

Tags: authentication, github, next.js

I am following https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres to make a website, but I keep getting error at Github authentication.

I did follow everything in the blog, only problem im facing is github authentication when im in development i have my site at http://localhost:3000/ when i click login i go to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin and see sign in with github, when i click that i go to https://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/github and i get The connection for this site is not securelocalhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

On production i get Try signing in with a different account.

Why do I go to https instead of http on my local environment. I have setup my Github Oauth application too, and the authorization callback url is set to, http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/github. What am i doing wrong.
Github: https://github.com/Montekkundan/csa_ufv